# Web SDK - Doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: aviary, adobecreativesdk

Aviary HTML5 Web SDK works fine for iOS laptop, Android phones, Windows laptops, but not iPhone.
Tested with iPhone safari browser and iPhone chrome browser.

Aviary feather loads, then "loading-spinner" icon keeps on spinning.

Is this a bug, or is mobile iOS not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Creative SDK for Web does not currently support phone-sized mobile devices, as noted in the [Getting Started guide for Web](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/web/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html):

> For handheld use we generally recommend our native SDKs (iOS, and Android), which have a UI optimized for smaller screens and performance tuned to the native device.

---

As one possible alternative, as of last week, there are **PhoneGap plugins** (compatible with PhoneGap, Cordova, and Ionic) that are available for the Creative SDK.

See the following blog posts to read more about the Creative SDK PhoneGap plugins:

- [PhoneGap plugins for the Creative SDK](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2016/08/phonegap-plugins-for-the-creative-sdk/)
- [PhoneGap template for the Creative SDK Image Editor](https://blog.creativesdk.com/2016/08/phonegap-template-for-the-creative-sdk-image-editor/)

The relevant plugin and template repos, with instructions and API guides, are available on GitHub:

- [Client Auth plugin](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-plugin-csdk-client-auth): The starting point for all Creative SDK integrations
- [Image Editor plugin](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-plugin-csdk-image-editor): the Creative SDK Image Editor for PhoneGap
- [Image Editor template](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-template-csdk-image-editor): An optional sample app template for quickstart

Comment: This is a great potential solution! I'm using the Image Editor as an editor for my online printing website. Its crucial that the editor can be launched from within the website, and sends the image to an S3 server when closed, all done while not leaving the website. Seeing this is an App, means that the PhoneGap will open the Image Editor separately. How do I let the "Phonegap Image Editor" communicate to my website, so my shopping cart can retrieve the edited image. The questions is, is this all possible? Thank you.

Comment: The Image Editor (and its PhoneGap plugin) don't offer this functionality. It might be possible to send the image (and the user) from your website to a standalone PhoneGap app with the Image Editor (say for example, via [URL schemes on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)), but getting them back into the workflow of your website would require some work. At that point, one path might be to have the user logged into the mobile app to edit their cart there.